# Which memory counter best describes the actual physical memory utilized by an application and is there a threshold value in perfmon for memory?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, memory-management, memory-limit, perfmon

I'm running some performance tests on client machine to capture the Response time and resource utilization by applications, which is the memory counter that i need to look at to get the right physical memory that is utilized by the application? Private bytes/Working set/Working set-Private or should I be looking at? Right now I use Perfmon to capture the Process CPU and memory, the application I'm testing is leaking memory, during the test, the private byte and Working set counter gets maxed at around 4GB and wont capture data beyond 4GB. I'm running this test on Windows 7 and Windows 10 machines and both give me the same result. I use splunk to capture the same data(my machines are live feeding all perfmon data into splunk), there I see the same counters reaching 12-14 GB(physical memory available on the machine is 16 GB). Need advise on why the perfmon data I capture through a powershell script hits the 4 GB threshold and am I looking at the right memory counters to capture the actual physical memory used.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking at the right PowerShell counters, if you see them stopping
at 4 GB.

This came up in another post that I can't locate now.
The conclusion that was arrived-at in this post was that these counters are 32-bit
and so cannot go above 4 GB.

Comment: Thanks Harry! I Today I ran a few more tests and saw the memory (private bytes)count go to 8 GB, I later continued the test and saw the same memory reaching 15 GB. The physical memory on the machine is 16 GB, the point where the private byte count reached 15 GB, the application stopped responding. Some times I see the memory go all the way beyond 4 GB, sometimes it gets restricted at 4GB, I dont understand this behavior of the counters.

Comment: Add to your post more info about what you are doing and how exactly you are getting these numbers and with what results. Your problem is a bit hard to understand.